# Генерация глобальных функций через цикл по списку

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Мне нужно использовать один URL и множество путей для связи с API по http запросам через библиотеку requests
Т.к. все методы используют по сути один только формат json с разными данными, я бы хотел сгенерировать глобальные функции

```
import requests
URL = "https://youtube.com/user/"
users = ["alpha","bravo","charlie","delta"]
for user in users:
    globals()[f] = lambda **args: requests.post(URL + users, json=args)

>>> alpha().url # возвращает url запроса
https://youtube.com/users/delta
>>> bravo(ключ = значние, ключ = значение).url #пример запроса с параметрами
https://youtube.com/users/delta
```

Я полагаю в том что функция возвращает данные для глобальной переменной users

Comment: Это редкий способ извращения. Зачем вы хотите это сделать? Если нужен набор функций - используйте списки или словари, но не генерацию переменных.

Comment: Мне они нужны, я хочу сделать функции с именами методов api для того что бы вызывать их многократно, т.к. информация обновляется. Использовать я их буду через цикл

Comment: Никогда не нужно использовать генерацию переменных. То что вы хотите еще не значит, что так нужно делать.

Comment: Вы делаете пост запрос. На что вы рассчитывали, когда писали это?

Comment: Мне нужно создать генератор функций который сработает лишь один раз, в списке будут названия методов для пост запросов (url/метод), т.к. пост запрос отправляется на один и тот же url но с разным путём я хочу создать функции, имена которых будут совпадать с именем метода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется лучше сделать одну функцию с параметрами и ее вызывать

Пример:

```
import requests

URL = "https://youtube.com/user/"

def send_post(user: str, **kwargs) -> requests.Response:
    return requests.post(URL + user, json=kwargs)

print(send_post('alpha').url)
print(send_post('bravo', ключ=значние, ключ=значение).url)
```

Comment: Помечу как ответ, но всё же хотелось иметь набор функций названия которых совпадают с методами, я так понял что в моём коде проблема лишь в том что цикл создаёт глобальные переменные user, а лямбда функция берёт именно глобальную. Нет ли способа изменить это?

Comment: @dznshfvt, это плохое решение :) Думаю примерно так: `globals()[user] = lambda **kwargs, user=user: requests.post(URL + user, json=kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

Создание глобальных переменных в рантайме (у вас - глобальных имен функций) - это довольно плохая идея. Вместо этого в данном случае лучше использовать словарь:

```
import requests

URL = "https://youtube.com/user/"
users = ["alpha","bravo","charlie","delta"]
functions = dict()

for user in users:
    functions[user] = lambda **args: requests.post(URL + users, json=args)

# Вызов:
functions["alpha"](**some_args)

# Вызов в цикле:
for user in users:
   functions[user](**some_args)
```

В вашем варианте вызов функций выглядел бы вот так:

```
alpha(**some_args)

for user in users:
   globals()[user](**some_args)
```

Вариант одиночного вызова как бы красивее (не нужно указывать название словаря, не нужны кавычки и квадратные скобки вокруг имени функции), но вызов в цикле выглядит примерно также. В целом, суть одна и та же, вызов из отдельного словаря и вызов из `globals()` работает одинаково (т.к. `globals()` - это словарь).

Основной недостаток вашего подхода в том, что при записи в `globals()` функции складываются в общее глобальное пространство имен, и если у вас случайно окажется пользователь с именем, как у какой-то глобальной переменной, которая у вас уже была, то значение вашей глобальной переменной заменится на функцию. К примеру, пользователь [requests](https://www.youtube.com/user/requests) (реально существующий) легко сломает работу вашей программы.

Поэтому, чтобы не было таких коллизий - лучше хранить наборы объектов сразу отдельно - в словарях или списках, а не складывать в глобальные переменные.

Comment: Зачем вызывать функцию из globals через цикл? Вместо globals()[name]() я могу писать name(). Пример с ютубом и пользователями это всего лишь пример, я не буду использовать такой подход для реальной работы. В начале скрипта можно определить пространство локальных имён и записывать функции методов туда. Мне нужно это для лёгкого доступа к методам в API, я не хочу много раз писать строки с названием метода внутри одной функции, я знаю как это будет использоваться и я не допущу перезапись зарезервированного слова в своём коде.

Comment: Мне нужно определить глобальные функции с названием метода чтобы получить более лёгкий вариант написания. Без этого мне нужно писать requests.post(url + methodName, json = dict(var1 = 33, var2 = 44)), но мне гораздо легче использовать methodName(var1 = 33, var2 = 44). Работа с API происходит через http запросы по типу url/method?var=a&id=33 . Все методы работают практически одинаково, но принимают разные поля, я понимаю что могу использовать обёртку для requests.post в виде post(methodName, **kwargs), но хочу избавить себя от того что бы лишний раз писать ковычки. Код создаётся в личных целях.